# Linq: Group by multiple columns using Expression-tree syntax

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, anonymous-types

I would like to change the following code so as to handle grouping of more than 1 property

```
private Expression<Func<ProfileResultView, string>> DynamicGroupBy(string propertyName)
{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProfileResultView), "x");
    var memberExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExp, propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<ProfileResultView, string>>(memberExp, parameterExp);
}
```

so then this would be translated to

```
GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2 })
```

how can I write the anonymous type in the expression-tree syntax?

Comment: An anonymous type is generated by the compiler and put into the output assembly. They cannot be generated dynamically at runtime in the same way. Now, you can generate such a type dynamically, but I'm pretty sure it won't work properly in a LINQ expression as you are attempting to use it now.

Comment: What LINQ provider are you going to be using this with? LINQ to objects? LINQ to Entities? Something else?

Comment: What about the return type of your method? now you have an expression returning a string, in your desired scenario it would return an anonymous type? It is not possible.
At the very least you will have to change your method to modify the queryable instead of returning the grouping expression. Then you can generate the types on the fly with IL, but its a bit ugly, not that fast, and you need to handle caching, and cleanup and lots of dirty bits :(

Comment: it is linq to Nhibernate....Is it possible to do with dynamic linq? through the dynamicQueryable class

Comment: I tried the following: var result = GetProfileResults(profileId).GroupBy("new(Regional)", "it").Select("new (it.Key)");

and received this exception: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: new DynamicClass1() {Regional = [100001].Regional}

Answer (score 0):

If the type of the grouping key does not matter for you, you can create types dynamically and call the grouping based on those types:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, object>> DynamicGroupBy<TSource>
       (params string[] properties)
{
    var entityType = typeof(TSource);
    var props = properties.Select(x => entityType.GetProperty(x)).ToList();
    var source = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");

    // create x=> new myType{ prop1 = x.prop1,...}
    var newType = CreateNewType(props);
    var binding = props.Select(p => Expression.Bind(newType.GetField(p.Name), 
                  Expression.Property(source, p.Name))).ToList();
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(newType), binding);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(body, source);
   return selector;
}
public static Type CreateNewType(List<PropertyInfo> props)
{
   AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName("MyAsm");
   AssemblyBuilder dynamicAssembly = AssemblyBuilder
       .DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
   ModuleBuilder dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("MyAsm");
   TypeBuilder dynamicAnonymousType = dynamicModule
       .DefineType("MyType", TypeAttributes.Public);

   foreach (var p in props)
   {
       dynamicAnonymousType.DefineField(p.Name, p.PropertyType, FieldAttributes.Public);
   }
   return dynamicAnonymousType.CreateType();
}
```

Note that the group key type is `object`.

Comment: This works for Group BY and Select as well. CAVEAT: the column must belong to the type TSource. So a naviagation/related column ie x.Column1.NestedColumn doesn't work.