# How to define an Anonymous type lambda parameter in Linq Expression

Tags: linq, .net-core, system.reflection

I had found in a stackoverflow post how they created an anonymous object but I would like to create a Lambda expression which select only a field within an object to be able to Group by Id

currently the coude from here [Linq: Group by multiple columns using Expression-tree syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523953/linq-group-by-multiple-columns-using-expression-tree-syntax)

creates a new type but I would like that it could be able to work on GroupBy linq method....

```cs
public static Type CreateNewType(List<PropertyInfo> props)
{
    AssemblyName asmName =  typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName();
    AssemblyBuilder dynamicAssembly = AssemblyBuilder
        .DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    ModuleBuilder dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("MyAsm");
    TypeBuilder dynamicAnonymousType = dynamicModule
        .DefineType("MyType", TypeAttributes.Public);

    foreach (var p in props)
    {
        dynamicAnonymousType.DefineField(p.Name, p.PropertyType, FieldAttributes.Public);
    }
    return dynamicAnonymousType.CreateType();
}
```

using this type using a single field(I only need the field rather the class... groups by an entity MyType which doesnt exist...it should group by either of the entities/fields in  my class

Comment: You do not need to create dynamic class for such case. Better explain what you plan to do with `IGrouping<T, TKey>`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Select a field property from an object dynamically, it could be whichever on runtime, but when I have used a lambda expression that is passed onto GroupBy then it doesnt groups by the key´s field inside the dynamic class... bur rather the class itself

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv maybe could I possibly be able to send a lambda  with a parameter name.Field so i could pick the key? maybe is there a way I can send this method field rather a type(on body)? Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(body, source), can I just reflect to select a field on an existing type?

Comment: Grouping itself has no benefits, except you need distinct keys.  Grouping has benefits when you use aggregation functions.  Which case do you have? Update answer with sample query without dynamic and mark what should be dynamic. Much better if you post signature of function which should do dynamic grouping, all parameters and result type are important.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i have found how to pass a lambda

Comment: Return back when you start defining aggregation ;) Remember that `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Field1, x.Fileld2 })` has no sense in SQL, but value comes from `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Field1, x.Fileld2 }).Select(g => new { g.Ke.Field1, g.Key.Field2, Count = g.Count(), Total = g.Sum(x => x.Price) })`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I dont have yet a solution to create an anonymous object to group by multiples columns but you are free to suggest a solution for that case

Comment: I have enough experience to build any LINQ query dynamically, but in your case I do not see reason to do that. As I told before, grouping itself has no sense. Describe what are you trying to achieve at the end.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv try to dinamically select the group certain items to return a queyr to js since there are many different combinations for each request from the front end so I might have to do many different combined requests

Comment: So it will be grouped items by some key serialised to JSON without any aggregations?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yeah it will only grouped by an individual property within the  select

Answer (score 0):

here I found that I can select a field from a lambda with the following code

```
        public Expression<Func<TSource,object>> DynamicPropertySelect<TSource>(ParameterExpression parameterExpression = null, params string[] properties)
        {
            var entityType = typeof(TSource);
            var props = properties.Select(x => entityType.GetProperty(x)).ToList();
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, props.First().Name), parameterExpression);
        }
```